# Bootstrap - Problems with Popovers/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started experimenting with bootstrap and I've ran into a few issues. Anything that uses JavaScript/jQuery just doesn't seem to work. I've tried default Bootstrap, and the theme I'm currently using "Darkly". Same issues on each.

This is the code on a page that uses a popover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- Basic
  ================================================== -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Amplitude Gaming</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Amplitude Gaming: Website Testing">
  <meta name="author" content="Little NEKO">
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Favicons
  ================================================== -->

</head>
<!-- Page Start
  ================================================== -->

  <body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="logo-nav"href="#"><img src="images/amplogo1.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="haste.html">Haste</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Testing popovers</p>

  <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Test</button>
</div>

</div>
<!-- End Document 
  ================================================== -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
  <!-- third party plugins  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see a live version here: http://www.amplitudegaming.com/test.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: @Skelly I've been trying everything and probably left it in by accident. Thanks for pointing that out. And thank you for the welcome! I should have joined a long time ago but now I've finally decided to be productive and this will help quite a bit.

Comment: Also, you have an extra div in your markup. Please clean it up before posting to SO, and a fiddle or bootply is better than linking to an external site. It shows that you made some debugging effort before posting your question.

Comment: @Skelly I've actually been debugging this for a few hours. I toggled the popover incorrectly, including through an external file worked.  Will post cleaner code and a bootply next time; thanks for the help and critique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate the popover using jQuery..

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

http://www.bootply.com/127692

Answer (score -1):

Including two jQuery file will cause the problem. You have included in header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then again in footer you have included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-plugin/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just remove one of the two.

Comment: Please edit your question so it is correctly formatted, as it stands it is unreadable and therefor not useful.